# Rails 4 minitest functional test failed for create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Here's my Code for controller

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and my code for testing

```
test "should get create post" do
  assert_difference('Post.count') do
    post :create, post: {title: @post.title, content: @post.content}
  end
  assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns{:post})
end
```

The error that I'm getting is

ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
    test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in '

if i remove (assigns{:post}) and try the test

i get this error

ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
Also how to test the if fails render 'new' part in controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the following line

```
assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns{:post})
```

use parenthesis instead of curly braces. The code should look like this:

```
assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
```

Answer (score 0):

`@post` is not instantiated anywhere in the test. You need to pass in params like so

`post :create, post: {title: 'title', content: 'content'}`

Comment: no this still doesn't work because i did include this in the beginning     setup do
    @post = posts(:one)
  end

Comment: What are your validations on the model? Don't forget that the fixtures are already loaded into the database, so if you have a unique constraint on `:title` or ':content`, the save will fail.